# How can I view website root when directory listing enabled?

Tags: apache, security, iis, directory-listing

I can view my websites subdirectory indexes. (domain.com/css)
But when i try to reach the root index server shows me the index.html file.

Is there a way to list the root directory?

Comment: You could rename index.html to something like page.html

Answer (score 0):

`DirectoryIndex disabled` should turn off indexes in apache. But it's beyond me why one would want to do that in real life.

Ref: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html